# How to use VisualCaptcha with AngularJS and slimPHP in RESTful

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, captcha, slim

So I use`AngularJS` on frontend and `SlimPHP` on backend with REST url. I am trying to use [VisualCaptch](http://visualcaptcha.net/) and I followed the instruction on the PHP side and it seems to work on the backend, I made a simple Angular dataService calling the url and display it on the console but I simply don't understand how to connect it with Angular, I downloaded also that portion but when I create the `HTML` and call the `captcha` inside the `<div>`. Well actually let me explain 1 of the problem, it's the url that the Angular is trying to run that is incorrect but I just don't know how to configure it, is there an option for? So let me display the code that I have so far... By the way, I use the `Controller as vm` syntax, so you will not find `$scope` in my code.
HTML:

```
<div captcha options="vm.captchaOptions"></div>
```

AngularJS Controller code:

```
// this work as a dataService call to SlimPHP
dataService.getCaptchaHowMany().then(function(data) {
    console.debug(data);
});

// where does my dataService call goes in here???
vm.captchaOptions = {
    imgPath: 'vendors/visual-captcha/img/',
    captcha: { numberOfImages: 5 },
    init: function ( captcha ) {
        vm.captcha = captcha;
    }
};
```

SlimPHP Routes, which I know they work

```
# Captcha Routes
$app->get('/captcha/start/:howMany', function($howMany) use ($app) { CaptchaController::getCaptchaHowMany($app, $howMany); });
$app->get('/captcha/audio(/:type)', function($type = 'mp3') use ($app) { CaptchaController::getCatpchaDiskAudioStreaming($app, $type); });
$app->get('/captcha/image/:index', function($index) use ($app) { CaptchaController::getCatpchaDiskImageStreaming($app, $index); });
$app->post('/captcha/try', function() use ($app) { CaptchaController::postCatchaTryValidate($app); });
```

When I copied over the example of VisualCaptcha with Angular and I run the code, it shows a bad url call (bad because my SlimPHP Api is in a different location). So the bad url call looks like this: 

`GET http://localhost/myproject/user/start/5`
But to make a proper call to my `SlimPHP` Api routes it should be like this
`GET http://localhost/myproject/api/captcha/start/5`

So where do I configure the routes for Angular with VisualCaptcha??? I have also attached the result of my proper url, so I think that my backend (SlimPHP) is properly working, it's just to configure the Angular url in the controller that is wrong.
[image]

**EDIT**
I got a bit further now, I found that we can set the `url` inside the `captchaOptions` which now makes a proper call to my `SlimPHP` api urls with the following

```
vm.captchaOptions = {
    imgPath: 'vendors/visual-captcha/img/',
    captcha: { 
        numberOfImages: 5,
        url: 'api/captcha'
    },
    // use init callback to get captcha object
    init: function ( captcha ) {
        vm.captcha = captcha;
    }
};
```

I now have the issue that it is not displaying the images. Are the images suppose to come from PHP or from Angular on the client side? Which folder should contain all images? I actually get this error message in the console:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost/investing/api/captcha/audio?r=353oeaysbjg failed.
```

I actually don't want audio, though it's giving me this audio error, I simply want to use the images, that's all. Could someone help me out, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After passing 2 days on this, I finally got it working. There is a couple of code change that I had to do.. so here is the list of modifications:

First, I was missing the session variable inside my `SlimPHP` application:

```
// Inject Session closure into app
$app->session = function() use( $app ) {
    if ( $namespace = $app->request->params( 'namespace' ) ) {
        $session = new \visualCaptcha\Session( 'visualcaptcha_' . $namespace );
    } else {
        $session = new \visualCaptcha\Session();
    }
    return $session;
};
```

Then changed the HTML code to work with `Bootstrap` instead of `Foundation`, also added 2 button to check if it's filled and if it's valid:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5">Visual Captcha Messages</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7" id="status-message">
        <div class="alert" ng-class="{ 'alert-danger': (vm.valid === false), 'alert-success': (vm.valid === true) }" role="alert" ng-show="vm.status !== null">
            <div ng-class="{ 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign': (vm.valid === false), 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign': (vm.valid === true) }" ></div>
            {{ vm.status }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5">Visual Captcha</label>                
    <div class="col-sm-7" captcha options="vm.captchaOptions"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="vm.isVisualCaptchaFilled()">Check if visualCaptcha is filled</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="vm.isVisualCaptchaValid()">Validate Catpcha</button>
```

then inside my `AngularJS` controller using the `Controller as vm` syntax:

```
vm = this;  
vm.captcha = {};
vm.captchaOptions = {
    imgPath: 'vendors/visual-captcha/img/', // vendors folder on Angular side, only used for "refresh" and "audio" buttons
    captcha: { 
        numberOfImages: 5,
        url: 'api/captcha'                  // url for SlimPHP route calls
    },
    // use init callback to get captcha object
    init: function ( captcha ) {
        vm.captcha = captcha;
    }
};

// vm public functions revealing
vm.isVisualCaptchaFilled = isVisualCaptchaFilled;
vm.isVisualCaptchaValid = isVisualCaptchaValid;

function isVisualCaptchaFilled() {
    if ( vm.captcha.getCaptchaData().valid ) {
        window.alert( 'visualCaptcha is filled!' );
    } else {
        window.alert( 'visualCaptcha is NOT filled!' );
    }
}

function isVisualCaptchaValid() {
    // we will post the captcha image field name and image field value
    var postData = {
        fieldName: vm.captcha.getCaptchaData().name,
        fieldValue: vm.captcha.getCaptchaData().value
    };

    dataService.isVisualCaptchaValid(postData)
        .then(function(data) {
            // Show success/error messages
            if ( data.status === 'noCaptcha' ) {
                vm.valid = false;
                vm.status = 'visualCaptcha was not started!';
            } else if ( data.status === 'validImage' ) {
                vm.valid = true;
                vm.status = 'Image was valid!';
            } else if ( data.status === 'failedImage' ) {
                vm.valid = false;
                vm.status = 'Image was NOT valid!';
            } else if ( data.status === 'validAudio' ) {
                vm.valid = true;
                vm.status = 'Accessibility answer was valid!';
            } else if ( data.status === 'failedAudio' ) {
                vm.valid = false;
                vm.status = 'Accessibility answer was NOT valid!';
            } else if ( data.status === 'failedPost' ) {
                vm.valid = false;
                vm.status = 'No visualCaptcha answer was given!';
            }
        })
        .then(function() {
            vm.captcha.refresh();
        });        
}
```

then also had to rewrite the `try` route inside the `SlimPHP` app:

```
// Try to validate the captcha
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$app->post( '/try', function() use( $app ) {
    $captcha = new \visualCaptcha\Captcha( $app->session );
    $frontendData = $captcha->getFrontendData();
    $isCaptchaValid = false;
    $namespace = '';
    $status = '';

    //POST variables, they come as a JSON encoded inside the POST
    $jsonPostFields = $app->request();
    $post = json_decode($jsonPostFields->getBody(), $associativeArray = true);

    // Load the namespace into url params, if set
    if ( isset($post['namespace']) ) {
        $namespace = $post['namespace'];
    }
    if ( ! $frontendData ) {
        $status = 'noCaptcha';
    } else {
        // If an image field name was submitted, try to validate it
        if(isset($post["fieldName"]) && $post["fieldName"] === $frontendData['imageFieldName']) {
            $imageAnswer = $post["fieldValue"];
            if ( $captcha->validateImage( $imageAnswer ) ) {
                $isCaptchaValid = true;
                $status = 'validImage';
            } else {
                $status = 'failedImage';
            }
        } else if(isset($post["fieldName"]) && $post["fieldName"] === $frontendData['audioFieldName']) {
            $audioAnswer = $post["fieldValue"];
            if ( $captcha->validateAudio( $audioAnswer ) ) {
                $isCaptchaValid = true;
                $status = 'validAudio';
            } else {
                $status = 'failedAudio';
            }
        } else {
            $status = 'failedPost';
        }
        $howMany = count( $captcha->getImageOptions() );
        $captcha->generate( $howMany );
    }
    echo json_encode(array("isCaptchaValid" => $isCaptchaValid, "status" => $status));
} );
```

Please notice that using a `dataService` was only for the testing & development purposes, you should instead validate the `VisualCaptcha` on the backend just before saving the form which is also on backend. So in theory, you would only have 1 call in Angular which is the form saving call through the `dataService`, then on the server backend side there would be 2 things that needs to happen (1- captcha validation, 2- saving form)

I also modified the data to `post` because I don't like the way they have done their example, I never directly post a form inside an AngularJS SPA application, I instead prefer to use a `dataService` called by an `ng-click` which is why I had to define my own `postData` variable.

With all these changes... it finally works on both Images & Audio!!!